# OmniSharp hangs when loading Cake.Bakery.exe

Tags: cakebuild

I am new to Cake. 
I am trying to configure IntelliSense for Cake VSCode as described here:
https://cakebuild.net/docs/integrations/editors/vscode/intellisense

I am getting the following OmniSharp error:

```
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.Services.CakeScriptService
        Using Cake.Bakery at C:/Work/VisibleFolder/Bakery/Cake.Bakery.0.5.1/Cake.Bakery.exe

[ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).
```

I've increased the timeout from 1 to 10 minutes. That didn't help. 
Re-installing extensions and re-starting VSCode also didn't help.

How can I troubleshoot Cake.Bakery.exe? Can I enable log for it?

I tried to follow the same steps on another VM. I got a different OmniSharp fail error:

`OmniSharp.Stdio.Host`

**Response**

```
{
  "Request_seq": 7,
  "Command": "/v2/codestructure",
  "Running": true,
  "Success": false,
  "Message": "\"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\\r\\n   at OmniSharp.Cake.Extensions.ResponseExtensions.<TranslateAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\src\\\\OmniSharp.Cake\\\\Extensions\\\\ResponseExtensions.cs:line 153\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at OmniSharp.Cake.Services.RequestHandlers.CakeRequestHandler`2.<Handle>d__14.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2.<GetFirstNotEmptyResponseFromHandlers>d__19.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2.<HandleRequestForLanguage>d__20.MoveNext() in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\src\\\\OmniSharp.Host\\\\Endpoint\\\\EndpointHandler.cs:line 230\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2.<Process>d__16.MoveNext() in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\src\\\\OmniSharp.Host\\\\Endpoint\\\\EndpointHandler.cs:line 131\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n   at OmniSharp.Stdio.Host.<HandleRequest>d__13.MoveNext() in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\src\\\\OmniSharp.Stdio\\\\Host.cs:line 215\"",
  "Body": null,
  "Seq": 28,
  "Type": "response"
}
```

Comment: we released [Cake.Bakery 0.6.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Bakery/) today which includes a couple of bug fixes. Could you try removing Bakery 0.5.1 and installing 0.6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing 0.6.2 (as per Augusto's comment) resolved the issue.
Thank you Augusto!